# Retrieve commit from a deleted branch in the remote

Tags: git, github

In the remote (on Github), I have a commit that was associated to a deleted branch.
I can see the commit and its parent on Github, but I can't access it from my local shell.

The parent (hash), however, is accessible.

I tried the following approaches (and some more from the web):

```
$ git fetch origin

$ git fetch origin eb9103f6cce6b2e4d83a909d07aec5f0e5b9c23b
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref eb9103f6cce6b2e4d83a909d07aec5f0e5b9c23b

$ git show eb9103f6cce6b2e4d83a909d07aec5f0e5b9c23b
fatal: bad object eb9103f6cce6b2e4d83a909d07aec5f0e5b9c23b
```

How can I get this commit and cherrypick it?

### Solution

As @larsmans proposed, I used the suggested [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) syntax but with a different call.

I  changed to apply from am because am broke complaining a merge cannot be done. apply worked though I had to re-add the changes.

```
hub apply https://github.com/team/project/commit/eb9103f6cce6b2e4d83a909d07aec5f0e5b9c23b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still see the commit on the GitHub web UI, you can use [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) to cherry-pick it by URL:

```
hub am https://github.com/team/project/commit/eb9103f6cce6b2e4d83a909d07aec5f0e5b9c23b
```

(`git fetch` will only fetch commits by refspec, i.e., they need to be the tip of a branch or tag.)

Answer (score 0):

Git never "loses" a commit if it has any children.  However, the internal Garbage Collection *may* remove objects it deems no longer needed.
One thing you could try is `git fsck --lost-found`
If that yields no results you are **SOL**.